# Button pressed on grid view without selection

Tags: c#, gridview

i have a button on win form , which delete row on grid view.

```
numberSettingTable.SelectedRows[0]
```

Problem is when i press the button without row selection it send null, in java -1 was return which tells that no rows are selected. So how can i achieve the same in c#?.

I have tried if statement

```
numberSettingTable.SelectedRows[0] != null
```

But it didnt worked.

Following is the error detail.

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at VetoSmsServer.mainForm.removeEntryBt_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\WorkSpace\VetoSmsServer\VetoSmsServer\mainForm.cs:line 310
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at VetoSmsServer.Program.Main() in C:\WorkSpace\VetoSmsServer\VetoSmsServer\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if there is any row selected in your `DataGridView` control. If there is you can delete the first selected or all selected. The following snippet is demonstrating deleting of the only one selected row. Also you should pay attention not to try to delete the new row that is uncommitted. Therefore, you could use the lines:

```
DataGridViewRow dgrvr = numberSettingTable.SelectedRows[0];
          if(!dgrvr.IsNewRow)
```

The full code snippet is like this:

```
if(numberSettingTable.SelectedRows.Count>0)
{
      DataGridViewRow dgrvr = numberSettingTable.SelectedRows[0];
      if(!dgrvr.IsNewRow)
           numberSettingTable.Rows.Remove(dgrvr);   
}
```

in order to delete multiple selected rows, just iterate trough SelectedRows collection.

Answer (score 1):

Perform this check instead

```
numberSettingTable.SelectedRows != null
```

Comment: You have an ArgumentOutOfRangeException with message *=Index was out of range* when you try to access an array, here you are not trying to access any array, so I can't understand how you can get this error unless you are accessing an array

Comment: I have already mentioned i am accessing an array. also on selected Rows this is returned. System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection

Comment: DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection  is a collection of the selected rows. If this is null then no row is selected. Hopefully, in java you weren't accessing numberSettingTable.SelectedRows[-1] because this too would have thrown an exception.

Comment: In substance, if there is no array (ie the array is null) you can't access it

Comment: on i am accessing [0]. on which give error. I just to want to make sure user hasnt selected a row so give him a proper message

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
   // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = YourGridView.SelectedRow;
   if(row != null)
   {
     . . . .. 
   }
```

Link  Complete sample : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx

2 Another solution based on `RowCommand event`

```
void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="Test")
    {
      // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
      // property to an Integer.
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: Sorry but there is no selectedrow in my grid view

Comment: With best practise you can also try with RowCommand event on your grid view

Comment: I'am happy to help you Great Majestics

Answer (score 0):

numberSettingsTable.SelectedRows will never be null, however if no rows are selected its Count property will be 0 (zero).

Check for that instead:

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{

}
```